# React Router createBrowserRouter and React Context

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am getting the following error when trying to access `useNavigate` from my context file:
`useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component`

I have seen other posts on this issue but none that are update using the new `createBrowserRouter` function.

I am trying to add my context provider inside of router but I still am getting the error.

```
const createRouter = () =>
  createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/:appTypeId/:submissionId/:referralMasterId?',
      element: (
        <AppProvider>
          <AppLayout />
        </AppProvider>
      ),
      id: 'root',
    },

  ])

export const AppRoutes: React.FC<{}> = ({}) => {
  return <RouterProvider router={createRouter()} />
}
```

Then in my AppLayout I use context:

```
  const {
    apiResponseMessage,
    currentUser,
    getAuthJWT,
    getCurrentUser,
    getReasonTypes,
    getReferTo,
    getReferralById,
    getReferralTypes,
    getSubmission,
  } = useContext(AppContext) as SelectedContextType
```

My context file is trying to use `useNavigate` however I keep getting the `useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`

```
export const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function getCurrentUser() {
    navigate("/test");
  }

  const appContext = {
    getCurrentUser,
  };
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={appContext}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AppProvider;
```

Comment: *Where* is any `useNavigate` hook being used? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve]?

Comment: Hey Drew, I can try to set that up. `useNavigate` is called in my `AppContext` file. The `AppProvider` is declared within the `createBrowserRouter` function so I am not sure why it wouldn't have access to that function.

Comment: *Where* in your `AppContext` file are you using the `useNavigate` hook? Inside the `AppProvider` component? Is your `AppContext` file/code/etc all part of the same project, you aren't importing it from an external library?

Comment: Still working on a reproducable example but I have added a snippet of my Context file and how I declare `useNavigate`

Comment: Thanks. That certainly appears to be a valid implementation. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?